# Only look for elements within the parent table, not the child tables within its cells

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sort of an odd question, but I'm having some trouble coming up with a good selector to do this. The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/NZf6r/1/

In short, I have a parent table which has a "select all" checkbox as a column in the `thead`. Every table row also has a checkbox. The intention is if they click the checkbox, I select (or deselect) all of the row checkboxes in the `tbody`. Simple, right?

However, there a rows in the table that function as child tables for each row. These child tables also have checkboxes and also have a need for the same "select all" scheme.

The tricky part is not getting the "select all" in the parent table to also select the children. My current event function looks like this (also on the jsfiddle):

```
$('th input').on('click', function(event) {
    var isChecked = $(event.target).is(':checked');
    $(event.target)
        .parents('table')
        .first()
        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
        .each(function(i, checkbox) {
            $(checkbox).prop('checked', isChecked);
        });
});
```

I know I can use direct child selectors (`>`), but I'm not quite sure of the best way to incorporate that.

I also know I could add a class to the checkboxes for each table type (parent vs. child) and add that to the input selector, but I'm curious if there's a way I can avoid doing that. Some jQuery magic, if you will.

Here is the rough HTML of things (not the full table, obviously) in case you can't access the jsfiddle:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20px">
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>Bar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Aaaaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-left: 20px">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>Bar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>Aaaaa</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                    
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>Bbbbb</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding-left: 20px">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </div>
                                </th>
                                <th>Bar</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>Bbbbb</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>                    
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle has it: http://jsfiddle.net/NZf6r/1/ . I'll edit the post anyway, though.

Comment: So you want to check the child but not the grandchild?

Comment: I don't follow the exact goal.  When you click which checkbox, then which checkboxes to you want automatically selected?  Usually, you would select child rows when a parent checkbox is selected.  Is that what you want?  The HTML is confusing because you're repeating the same labels so that makes it more complicated to explain in terms of a click on the top level "Aaaaa" means to select which other checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this script instead:

```
$('th input').on('click', function(event){
  var parenttable = $(this).parents('table:first');
  var isChecked = $(event.target).is(':checked');
  parenttable.find(">tbody>tr>td>div>input").prop('checked', isChecked);
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know you could START a selector with `>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/kUH64/1/)

```
$('th input').on('click', function (event) {
    var isChecked = $(event.target).is(':checked');

    $(event.target)
        .closest("table")
        .find('> tbody > tr:not(:has(table)) > td  input[type="checkbox"]')
        .each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
});
```